# Program crashes while using struct tm unless time_t declared first

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to prevent recreating the wheel.  I am parsing an input file that has time as one of the values.  I need a data structure to hold all of the values of the input file, and instead of creating a custom structure for the time field I want to just use struct tm from ctime.

I'm running into a strange error though, so hopefully one of you can help me out.  Here's my test code (for my proof of concept):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{

int Oldhour = 16;
int OldSecond = 25;
int OldMinute = 20;

time_t seconds;

struct tm * timeinfo;

timeinfo->tm_hour = Oldhour;
timeinfo->tm_min = OldMinute;
timeinfo->tm_sec = OldSecond;


int hour, min, sec;

hour = timeinfo->tm_hour;
min = timeinfo->tm_min;
sec = timeinfo->tm_sec;

printf("%d:%d:%d", hour, min, sec);

return 0;
}
```

This compiles just fine and it does exactly what I want and prints "16:20:25" so it's storing the info the way I want.  However if I remove the line "time_t seconds;" it crashes immediately.

Comment: If there's an answer which solves you're problem you should click to accept it.

Comment: I posted at the end of the work day, so I'm just now getting back to check answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to allocate the structure either on the stack or on the heap with malloc.  Specifically, you're declaring a pointer to the struct without allocating any storage for it.

Try this:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{

int Oldhour = 16;
int OldSecond = 25;
int OldMinute = 20;

time_t seconds;

struct tm timeinfo;

timeinfo.tm_hour = Oldhour;
timeinfo.tm_min = OldMinute;
timeinfo.tm_sec = OldSecond;


int hour, min, sec;

hour = timeinfo.tm_hour;
min = timeinfo.tm_min;
sec = timeinfo.tm_sec;

printf("%d:%d:%d", hour, min, sec);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple.  Of course, that still doesn't explain why it works when "time_t seconds" is declared first.